# How to connect php code to database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am editing a laravel project and I would like to add a signature feature. I have this code down below that is mobile responsive. But I couldn't figure out how to connect it to an existing
Lets say for example that server name: localhost. username: db_test. password:db123. database name:db_test

the table I want to insert it in is $booking->signature.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['signaturesubmit'])){ 
    $signature = $_POST['signature'];
    $signatureFileName = uniqid().'.png';
    $signature = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $signature);
    $signature = str_replace(' ', '+', $signature);
    $data = base64_decode($signature);
    $file = 'signatures/'.$signatureFileName;
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Signature Uploaded</div>";
} 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        #canvasDiv{
            position: relative;
            border: 2px dashed grey;
            height:300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <br>
                <?php echo isset($msg)?$msg:''; ?>
                <h2>Sign Here</h2>
                <hr>
                <div id="canvasDiv"></div>
                <br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="reset-btn">Clear</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-save">Save</button>
            </div>
            <form id="signatureform" action="" style="display:none" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" id="signature" name="signature">
                <input type="hidden" name="signaturesubmit" value="1">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
        canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
        $("#canvas").attr('height', $("#canvasDiv").outerHeight());
        $("#canvas").attr('width', $("#canvasDiv").width());
        if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
            canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
        }
        
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e) {
            var offset = $(this).offset()
            var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

            paint = true;
            addClick(e.pageX - offset.left, e.pageY - offset.top);
            redraw();
        });

        $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
            if (paint) {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                //addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
                addClick(e.pageX - offset.left, e.pageY - offset.top, true);
                console.log(e.pageX, offset.left, e.pageY, offset.top);
                redraw();
            }
        });

        $('#canvas').mouseup(function(e) {
            paint = false;
        });

        $('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e) {
            paint = false;
        });

        var clickX = new Array();
        var clickY = new Array();
        var clickDrag = new Array();
        var paint;

        function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
            clickX.push(x);
            clickY.push(y);
            clickDrag.push(dragging);
        }

        $("#reset-btn").click(function() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth);
            clickX = [];
            clickY = [];
            clickDrag = [];
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#btn-save', function() {
            var mycanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var img = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            anchor = $("#signature");
            anchor.val(img);
            $("#signatureform").submit();
        });

        var drawing = false;
        var mousePos = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };
        var lastPos = mousePos;

        canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
            mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
            var touch = e.touches[0];
            var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
                clientX: touch.clientX,
                clientY: touch.clientY
            });
            canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
        }, false);


        canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
            var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
            canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
        }, false);


        canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {

            var touch = e.touches[0];
            var offset = $('#canvas').offset();
            var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
                clientX: touch.clientX,
                clientY: touch.clientY
            });
            canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
        }, false);



        // Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
        function getTouchPos(canvasDiv, touchEvent) {
            var rect = canvasDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
                y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
            };
        }


        var elem = document.getElementById("canvas");

        var defaultPrevent = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        elem.addEventListener("touchstart", defaultPrevent);
        elem.addEventListener("touchmove", defaultPrevent);


        function redraw() {
            //
            lastPos = mousePos;
            for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
                context.beginPath();
                if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
                } else {
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
                }
                context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
    })

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials out there that show how to uonnect to a mysql database from php. There is not even an attempt in your code to connect to a database, so we do not know what you are struggling with!

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the DB credentials in .env file. It's in the root of your project. If it does not exists, you can rename .env.example and make changes to it.

Based on your code (interaction with database in view is not standard in an MVC framework, atleast), I think it's better to get familiar with laravel first. There are a lot resources to learn it.

Comment: hahaha, beat me by 30 sec

Comment: That happens :) but it's not a competition. Good luck.

Comment: yes, of course not. But i thought i'd share. Have a good day.